# Structure of most jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Why most jQuery plugins are based on structure:

```
(function($)
{
    // do stuff with $
})(jQuery)
```

I think this structure is equivalence with this plain structure:

```
// do stuff with object 'jQuery'
```

As i think the 1st structure defines a function and call it with input parameter `jQuery`, Why we should do this, We can ignore the function and execute our code with object `jQuery` without any additional function
Can someone tell me why the 1st structure is better and more be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is (almost entirely) equivalent. The reason to do this is mostly convenience, it's a pain to write out `jQuery` every single time, and it's less idiomatic than just using `$`. There's a problem, however: many other popular javascript libraries use a `$` function, so jQuery can be loaded in "[no conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)" mode where it doesn't set the global variable `$`. In order for plugins to reference it in either no-conflict or normal mode, they include wrapping it in a function as you noticed.

As a side benefit, any `var` statements inside the "do stuff" region become function local, instead of global.

Answer (score 2):

The `(function($) {` and `})(jQuery)` parts are meant to keep variables savely inside the function to avoid conflicts with other code or other plugins.

A plugin function is defined like this:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.do_stuff = function() {

        //Do stuff

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It's valuable and helpful